# ¿Por qué necesitamos un string "al estilo C" para introducir texto en un fichero binario en C++?

Tags: c++, string

Cada vez que intentamos introducir en un fichero binario un registro en el cual sus campos contienen texto, tratamos de darle un tamaño fijo a éste usando una matriz de caracteres "al estilo C".

¿Por qué esto es necesario y no podemos hacerlo con el tipo de dato predefinido `string`?

```
// Aquí os dejo un ejemplo más ilustrativo:
 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
/* "#include <string>" no lo usamos al no estar permitido introducir
   en nuestro fichero cadenas de caracteres "al estilo C++". */
using namespace std;

const int LIMITE = 15;

typedef struct
{
    char campoTexto[LIMITE]; // Cadena de caracteres "al estilo C".
    char campoTexto2[LIMITE]; 
} tRegistro;

tRegistro reg;
ofstream fBin;

int main() // Solo trataremos de introducir el registro en el fichero:
{
    reg = {"hola", "lector"}; // Inicializamos el registro...

    fBin.open("ejemplo.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (!fBin.fail() && fBin.is_open())
    {
        fBin.write((char *) &reg, sizeof(reg));
        fBin.close();

    } else cout << "Se ha producido un error. Intentelo de nuevo...";

    return 0;
}
```

Además, también me surgen dudas con esta sentencia:

```
fBin.write((char *) &reg, sizeof(reg));
```

¿Por qué necesitamos pasar un puntero con la dirección de memoria de nuestro registro y no el registro en sí?

Comment: No queda nada claro tu pregunta: `fBin << string;` funciona **perfectamente**.

Comment: Antonio, te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a mi respuesta, creo que te será de utilidad para comprender exactamente por qué una forma funciona y la otra no. Además, te explico cómo hacer que funcione.

Comment: Por cierto, disculpa por no haber leído la última pregunta (*¿Por qué necesitamos pasar un puntero con la dirección de memoria de nuestro registro y no el registro en sí?*). ¿Quieres que te la responda en la misma respuesta o creas una nueva pregunta para no alargar más esta respuesta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya con el código ya se puede entender la pregunta, gracias por publicarlo.

> ¿Por qué esto es necesario y no podemos hacerlo con el tipo de dato
> predefinido "string"?

Para explicar con mas detalle, resolvamos esta otra duda primero.

---

> Además, también me surgen dudas con esta sentencia:
>
> ```
>   fBin.write((char *) &reg, sizeof(reg));
> ```
>
> ¿Por qué necesitamos pasarle un puntero con la dirección de memoria de
> nuestro registro, y no el registro en sí?

Lo que estas haciendo ahí es serializar los datos. Esto es como tomar una foto
de la memoria en ese momento, que vas a restaurar después.

La forma en la que lo haces es re-interpretando la memoria en la que esta tu
registro (en este caso deberías usar `reinterpret_cast`, no un cast "estilo C"
y deberías castear a un puntero constante, no uno normal) como un array de
caracteres.

---

Ya entendiendo esto, regresamos a la pregunta principal. La clase `std::string`
de una forma super simplificada<sup>1</sup> puede verse algo como esto:

```cpp
class string {
    char *contents = nullptr;
    size_t size = 0;
}
```

Que pasa cuando re-interpretas la memoria igual que antes? Que en lugar de
"tomar una foto" a los contenidos de el `string`, le tomaras una foto a el
puntero que indica donde están los datos, y al tamaño de los mismos. Por eso es
que `std::string` no se puede utilizar si tratas de serializar los datos de esa
manera.

Entonces el que no puedas usar `std::string` es el resultado de el método que
usas para serializar, que es literalmente copiar la memoria que ocupa tu
objeto, y re-interpretarla como un array de caracteres.

**1:** En realidad tiene otros atributos mas, por ejemplo un buffer para SSO,
pero eso no es relevante en este caso, así que lo omitiremos.

Comment: Hola, Pablo. Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, me has ayudado muchísimo, pero hay una cosa que no me queda clara; ¿qué es serializar y por qué tenemos la necesidad de hacerlo en este caso?

Comment: Serializar es tomar los bytes en la memoria que ocupa el objeto para guardarlos y restaurarlos mas tarde. Es como tomar una foto a la memoria del objeto. Con respecto al porque tenemos que hacerlo en este caso, ni la menor idea, depende de donde sacaste tu ejemplo y lo que estes aprendiendo.

Answer (score 4):

**¿Por qué esto es necesario y no podemos hacerlo con el tipo de dato predefinido "string"?**

Estás haciendo uso del método de clase [`ostream.write()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) (`ofstream` hereda métodos de `ostream`) por voluntad propia:

> ostream& write (const char* s, streamsize n);

Por lo tanto usas:

```
fBin.write((char *) &reg, sizeof(reg));
```

Pero podías hacer uso del [operador `<<` de `string`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3C%3C/), que permite agregar el contenido de la cadena a un `ostream`:

> ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const string& str);

Por lo tanto podrías usar, en su lugar:

```
fBin << reg.campoTexto << reg.campoTexto2;
```

Habiendo definido `reg` como `string`:

```
typedef struct
{
    string campoTexto;
    string campoTexto2;
} tRegistro;
```

Además, en esta ocasión escribirá solo la cadena de caracteres y no los caracteres de relleno hasta llegar a `LIMITE` caracteres (15), por lo que quizá desees agregar un separador entre ambas cadenas y un retorno del carro final:

```
fBin << reg.campoTexto << ", " << reg.campoTexto2 << std::endl;
```

En tu código estás forzando la escritura de 30 octetos de datos en el archivo, justo el tamaño de la estructura, rellenando con caracteres nulos (`\0`) los "huecos" entre ambas palabras.

---

**¿Por qué no podemos hacer directamente `fBin << reg;`?**

No podemos hacerlo porque tu estructura no tiene implementado qué hacer con el operador `<<`, por lo que si tratas de hacer uso de esa construcción te dirá que no existe una implementación de dicho operador entre algo de tipo `std::ofstream` y algo de tipo `tRegistro`:

> pr.cpp:26:7: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ofstream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ofstream’} and ‘tRegistro’)

Para hacer que funcione de esa forma tienes que definir el comportamiento con el operador `<<` de la siguiente manera:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& entrada, const tRegistro& a)
{
    return entrada << a.campoTexto << ", " << a.campoTexto2 << std::endl;
}
```

Además, debes cambiar la definición de la estructura por ésta:

```
struct tRegistro
{
    string campoTexto;
    string campoTexto2;
};
```

De modo que ahora podrás hacer:

```
fBin << reg;
```

Sin que funcione mal ni provoque errores.

Código completo usado para probar este código:

```js
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct tRegistro
{
    string campoTexto;
    string campoTexto2;
};

tRegistro reg;
ofstream fBin;

/* Aquí implementamos el comportamiento de la estructura con el operador << */
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& entrada, const tRegistro& a)
{
    return entrada << a.campoTexto << ", " << a.campoTexto2 << std::endl;
}

int main() // Solo trataremos de introducir el registro en el fichero:
{
    reg = {"hola", "lector"}; // Inicializamos el registro...

    fBin.open("ejemplo.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (!fBin.fail() && fBin.is_open())
    {
        /* Ahora podemos enviar al archivo directamente la estructura */
        fBin << reg;
        fBin.close();

    } else {
        cout << "Se ha producido un error. Intentelo de nuevo...";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios @Pablochaches , por desgracia se me escapó el publicar respuesta cuando quise ver la tuya. Ya la he completado.